# Конфликт между document.getElementById()

Tags: html, javascript, get

Здравствуйте уважаемые добродетели =)
Помогите пожалуйста ;)
Есть код:

```
var tmp_linkpricelow = Array;
var linklabel = Array;
var n = 1;

tmp_linkpricelow[n] = document.getElementById("linkpricelow" + n);
tmp_linkpricelow[n].placeholder = (localStorage["linkpricelow" + n] == ('' || 0)) ? '' : localStorage["linkpricelow" + n];

console.log("1.pricelowholder =" + tmp_linkpricelow[n].placeholder);

linklabel[n] = document.getElementById("linklabel" + n);
linklabel[n].innerHTML = (localStorage["linkname" + n] == '') ? 'nope' : "<a href=\"" + localStorage["link" + n] + "\"target=\"_blank\">" + localStorage["linkname" + n] + "</a>";

console.log("2.pricelowholder =" + tmp_linkpricelow[n].placeholder);
```

Есть html:

```
<div class="form__row form__row_msg-list">
    <div class="form__row__label label_yes">
        <label for="interface" id="linklabel1">link 1</label>
    </div>
        <div class="form__row__widget">
            <div>
                <input class="info" value="" placeholder="steam link" id="link1" size="45">
            </div>
        </div>
    <div><input class="info" value="" id="linkpricelow1" size="1"></div>
</div>
```

localStorage - переменная расширения в Google Chrome
Вопрос: почему в консоль вывод правильный работает только если отключить строку:
    linklabel[n] = document.getElementById("linklabel" + n);

Кто объяснит такое странное явление? Спасибо заранее

Comment: Попробуйте объявлять массив не через Array, а new Array или через []. (var linklabel = [];)

Comment: Спасибо, все помогло.

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Как уже сказал [[@Genson](/users/6139/genson)](/users/6139/genson), массив нужно объявлять через литералы. В вашем случае это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
var linklabel = [];
```

То, что сделали вы - переменной `linklabel` будет присвоено встроенный в каждый браузер объект Array (вообще, правильнее говоря объект, на который ссылается переменная Array). Далее Вы этот встроенный объект расширяете свойством "`1`", которому присваете значение найденного DOM-элемента (то что возвращает функция document.getElementById). Посмотрите вывод консоли при вызове следующей функции:

```
console.log(Array);
```

У вас должен быть там объект Array со свойством 1.

Теперь о том, как сделать правильно. После объявления переменной `linklabel` так, как я показал выше. Вы должны добавить в этот новый массив какое-либо значение. Делается это с помощью в функции push, которая объявлена в прототипе объекта Array, а следовательно доступна каждому созданному массиву.

```
linklabel.push(document.getElementById("linkpricelow" + n));
```

Теперь в вашем массиве С ИНДЕКСОМ [0] будет добавлен найденный DOM. Чтобы обратиться к этому объекту (в Javascript практически всё - объекты), нужно написать следующее:

```
linklabel[0].placeholder //либо linklabel.0.placeholder
```

P.S. Массив можно создать и при помощи оператора new:

```
var linklabel = new Array();
```

Но у этого способа есть один нюанс. Вы не должны трогать переменную Array. Т.е. можно сделать так:

```
Array = function(){
    this.hello = 'Hello';
    console.log('Array said: ' + this.hello);
};
```

Тогда при таком подходе создания, будет создан не массив, а Ваш объект, а в консоле будет выведено нечто вроде: `Array said: Hello`

Comment: Большое спасибо попробую =)

Все заработало =)

Проблема в неправильном объявлении переменных. Вместо
var tmp_linkpricelow = Array;
var linklabel = Array;

Нужно писать так:
var tmp_linkpricelow = new Array();
var linklabel = new Array();

Всем спасибо ;)

Comment: @aH6y, не надо так писать. [Google JavaScript Style Guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Array_and_Object_literals):Array and Object literals:  

> Используйте литералы вместо явных конструкторов Array и Object.

Comment: Получается лучше объявлять массив вот так?
var a4 = [];

Comment: Ну я же Вам ясно написал почему так объявлять лучше... Вы немножко вверх посмотрите.

Comment: Да, все понял ;)
Еще раз большое спасибо =)
Всего доброго Вам =)